# Does $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ on Metric spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

supposed we have a metric space $(X,d)$ i have to prove that
$d(x,z)$ + $d(y,w)$ $\geq$ $- d(x,y)$ $+d(z,w)$.

I got it to a point that i have $d(x,z)$  $+d(x,y)$  $+d(y,w)$ $\geq$  $+d(z,w)$ $(1)$ .

Since $X$ Is a metric space does that mean that i can write $d(x,y)$ $=$ $d(y,x)$ and prove $(1)$ through
triangle inequality ?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a metric? What are the properties that every metric has?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee i know in fact that $d(x,y)$ $=$ $d(y,x)$ for every $x$,$y$ but could the answer be that simple?

Comment: "but could the answer be that simple?" why would it be hard? The only thing you've got to work with is the triangle inequality so the answer can't be anything *harder* than "apply the triangle inequality a bunch of times".

Comment: $d(x,z) + d(y, w) \ge -d(x,y) + d(z,w) \iff d(x,z) + d(y,w) + d(x,y) \ge d(z,w)$.  And $\underbrace{\underbrace{d(x,y)+d(y,w)}+d(x,z)}\ge \underbrace{d(x,w) + d(x,z)}=\underbrace{d(w,x)+ d(x,z)} > d(w,z)= d(z,w)$.  That's all.

Comment: Definitions are  tools. Get to know them well and always use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, yes. We have

$$ d(x, z) + d(x, y) + d(y, w) = d(z,x) + d(x,y) + d(y,w) $$

and the inequality follows from applying the triangle inequality twice.

Comment: Looks like its true that sometimes we overthink our answers, thanks!